# PyMySql cursor fetch all return empty when database has rows in python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Following is the code, i get the result as empty array but **cursor has rows shows rowcount > 1** :

``

```
def __init__(self,readLink):
    if readLink==0:
        self.linksToRead = 1000000000
    else:
        self.linksToRead = readLink
    self.linkCount = 0
    self.wordsList =[]
    self.parsedLinks=[]
    self.urlList =[]
    self.connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='root',
                         password='s3cr3tp@ssw0rd',
                         db='scrapper',
                         charset='utf8',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor, autocommit=True)


    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:

        sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `linksparsed`"
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql2)
            #self.connection.commit()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cursor.rowcount  #shows 3
        totalLength = len(result) # shows 0
        for row in result:
            self.parsedLinks.append(row)
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `for row in result`. Cursor itself is not iterable. Also, what array are you referring to? In Python, array is a specific data structure and should not be conflated with list or tuple. And where does cursor show rowcount?

Comment: i have tried and updated the question with result, the result is empty actually so its not working, row count is 3 when i do 'cursor.rowcount`

Comment: Where do you initialize cursor? And again where do you run `rowcount`. We want to reproduce your issue on our end. We may need to see more of your class. And you may need to qualify cursor with `self.`.

Comment: What is `totalLength` equal?

Comment: is there any problem with the library ? or am i missing something

Comment: How does this work? I get an AttributeError with your context manager `with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:` which should be `with self.connection as cursor` and `pymysql.connect()` does not have a *password* argument but **passwd**. Finally I cannot recreate your issue running several tables: `cursor.rowcount` always equals *totalLength*. What is the correct count for *linksparsed*: 0 or 3? Maybe other scripts/apps/transactions write to table?

Comment: I think that there something missing in your issue, but cannot figure out what it is. I ran your script it it seems to work fine. 

With that said, I my suggest doing the ` with self.connection.cursor() as cursor` inside a different method, rather than part of the `__init__`? that might help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the rownumber after `fetchall()` ? 
if it is 3, equals to rowcount, means have already fetched rows.

This is the source codes of fetchall, suppose return at "result  self._rows[self.rownumber:]"

```
def fetchall(self):
    """Fetch all the rows"""
    self._check_executed()
    if self._rows is None:
        return ()
    if self.rownumber:
        result = self._rows[self.rownumber:]  <<-------
    else:
        result = self._rows
    self.rownumber = len(self._rows)
    return result
```